# Regex match first group with "-"

Tags: regex

I have 2 different words:

```
BB50AR-B0N5-001-UNI
F361424500
```

In the first case where `-` is there, I want the first group as `BB50AR-B0N5-001` i.e last group should not come

In the second case where `-` is not there, I want the first group as `F361424500`

My attempt:

```
([\w]+)([-]?)(.*?)($)
```

The above regex is giving the reverse

Comment: Please update with your own attempt =)

Comment: @JvdV Added my attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use: `^(.+?)(?:-[^-]+?)?$`

With:

- `^`: beginning of the string
- `(.+?)`: capturing group, with:

  - `.+?`: any character, one or unlimited times, non greedy
- `(?:-[^-]+?)?`: non capturing group, 0 or 1 time, with:

  - `-[^-]+?`: a `-`, anything excepted `-` one or unlimited times, non greedy
- `$`: end of the string

Example: https://regex101.com/r/D55yEL/3/

Answer (score 3):

Maybe one of these two options could help you out. If your pattern would always be the same two possible strings:

```
^\w+(-\w+){0,2}
```

Check the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JnWV5J/3)

Or if you simply want to exclude the last part of a string if it's delimited:

```
^\w+$|.+(?=-)
```

Check the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JnWV5J/2).

Comment: I have accepted the other answer just because it was given first. Please don't mind. Your solution works fine too